# Lookup values from one dataframe to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling to lookup values from one dataframe to another. Tried concat and merge but looks like I'm not doing it correctly.

My first data frame d1

```
       SYMBOL SERIES      OPEN     HIGH       LOW     CLOSE      LAST  PREVCLOSE  TOTTRDQTY     TOTTRDVAL    TIMESTAMP  TOTALTRADES          ISIN       DATE TYPE    DEL      action  price_chng  action_mean   del_mean  delvery_cng  action_cng
0    AARTIIND     EQ    922.00    938.3    915.00    916.90    921.55     919.30     624883  5.791385e+08  23-FEB-2022        25225  INE769A01020 2022-02-23   EQ  37.94   24.772369   -0.261752    24.794340  39.331053    -3.666454   -0.088615
1         ABB     EQ   2076.00   2120.0   2076.00   2097.20   2100.25    2067.30     192678  4.052716e+08  23-FEB-2022        25281  INE117A01022 2022-02-23   EQ  53.21    7.621455    1.425710    10.993800  51.864737     2.528215  -30.674972
2  ABBOTINDIA     EQ  16751.10  17069.9  16625.05  17021.25  17000.15   16714.75      27205  4.608862e+08  23-FEB-2022         7932  INE358A01014 2022-02-23   EQ  36.42    3.429778    1.800690     3.207655  38.241579    -5.001590    6.924786
3   ABCAPITAL     EQ    108.90    109.8    107.40    108.10    108.05     108.00    2906398  3.151837e+08  23-FEB-2022        18569  INE674K01013 2022-02-23   EQ  28.83  156.518822    0.092507   192.114799  33.197368   -15.148694  -18.528493
4       ABFRL     EQ    266.95    271.4    263.50    269.10    269.90     263.00    1658245  4.456953e+08  23-FEB-2022        18279  INE647O01011 2022-02-23   EQ  30.42   90.718584    2.266815    95.409679  30.428421    -0.027683   -4.916791
```

My second data frame df2

```
DATE        01-FEB-2022  02-FEB-2022  03-FEB-2022  04-FEB-2022  07-FEB-2022  08-FEB-2022  09-FEB-2022  10-FEB-2022  11-FEB-2022  14-FEB-2022  15-FEB-2022  16-FEB-2022  17-FEB-2022  18-FEB-2022  21-FEB-2022  22-FEB-2022  23-FEB-2022  24-FEB-2022  25-FEB-2022  28-FEB-2022
SYMBOL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
AARTIIND            NaN     0.252908     0.045227    -0.001366     0.524515     0.064772    -0.124052    -0.071692     0.050795     0.007892    -0.054649    -0.026747    -0.013475     0.042236    -0.013278    -0.005767    -0.031640    -0.411145     0.053021     0.033372
ABB                 NaN     0.109300    -0.042351    -0.006318     0.007266     0.074842     0.010067     0.340532     0.013631     0.046455     0.186916     0.218504    -0.009289    -0.043212    -0.094163     0.014111    -0.068646    -0.370518     0.077532    -0.000734
ABBOTINDIA          NaN     0.120245     0.156900     0.032663     0.001146     0.023581     0.264818    -0.057471    -0.044841    -0.037910    -0.026950     0.018044     0.001855     0.019338    -0.038951    -0.092608    -0.144642    -0.534091     0.104530     0.137224
ABCAPITAL           NaN     0.110602     0.029893    -0.017158    -0.015174     0.007787     0.024166     0.004494     0.000959    -0.011973    -0.003716     0.014272     0.014711     0.002679     0.009430    -0.015102    -0.004584    -0.266000     0.019905     0.014001
ABFRL               NaN     0.017650     0.127609     0.142428    -0.023205    -0.000112    -0.034069    -0.006149     0.040276     0.014252     0.001881     0.014909    -0.010664    -0.023097    -0.042108    -0.061119    -0.019154    -0.310147     0.122109     0.020115
```

I want to create a new column called oi in the first data frame df1, which will be the value looked up based on Symbol & Timestamp of df1 found  in df2. For example,

Adanient 28-Feb-22  should return the value from df2 row Adanient and column 28-Feb-22 in df1['oi']

Comment: This can be done using https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html. 
Can you add clear dataframe sample to question?
Like `df.head(5).to_dict()` or something.

Comment: Do not paste code examples or sample data into comments, edit your question and format it as easily copied code.

Comment: **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: noted. made the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Use `melt` to flatten your second dataframe then `merge` to the first one on SYMBOL and TIMESTAMP columns:

```
out = (
  df1.merge(df2.reset_index().melt('SYMBOL', var_name='TIMESTAMP', value_name='oi'), 
            how='left', on=['SYMBOL', 'TIMESTAMP'])
)
```

Output:

```
>>> out[['SYMBOL', 'TIMESTAMP', 'oi']]
       SYMBOL    TIMESTAMP        oi
0    AARTIIND  23-FEB-2022 -0.031640
1         ABB  23-FEB-2022 -0.068646
2  ABBOTINDIA  23-FEB-2022 -0.144642
3   ABCAPITAL  23-FEB-2022 -0.004584
4       ABFRL  23-FEB-2022 -0.019154
```

Comment: Get a key error on the melt functionraise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'SYMBOL'

Comment: Your column name is not `SYMBOL`? It works with your sample.

Comment: df1.reset_index(inplace=True) before this worked!!